# Setting TextView's left drawable with Fresco

Tags: android, fresco

I've been struggling with this for a while now, using this guide:

http://frescolib.org/docs/writing-custom-views.html

But it suggests writing my own onDraw method, I just want to set TextView's compound drawable. How do I do that?

Comment: Why don't you do it using an ImageView on the left side of the TextView?

Comment: @user2520215 I don't want an extra view in the hierarchy

Comment: have you googled? setCompountintrisict blah blah blah, sorry about that i have forgotten the method. i just [researched](https://www.google.com/search?q=Textview+setcompoundintrisic&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) it now

Comment: You can try extending TextView, adding a background on the left side, and giving it a default paddingLeft of size: width of the drawble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to override onDraw, since TextView already does that for you. You can do something like this:

```
class MyTextView extends TextView {
  MultiDraweeHolder mMultiDraweeHolder;

  // called from constructors
  private void init() {
    mMultiDraweeHolder = new MultiDraweeHolder<GenericDraweeHierarchy>();
    GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder builder = 
        new GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder(getResources());
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      GenericDraweeHierarchy hierarchy = builder.reset()
        .set...
        .build();
      mMultiDraweeHolder.add(
          new DraweeHolder<GenericDraweeHierarchy>(hierarchy, getContext()));
  }
```

To actually set URIs and bounds:

```
// build DraweeController as in Fresco docs
DraweeHolder<GenericDraweeHierarchy> holder = mMultiDraweeHolder.get(i);
holder.setController(controller);
holder.getTopLevelDrawable().setBounds(...)
```

To assign them to your TextView:

```
List<Drawable> drawables = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  drawables.add(mMultiDraweeHolder.get(i).getTopLevelDrawable());
}
setCompoundDrawables(
    drawables.get(0), drawables.get(1), drawables.get(2), drawables.get(3));
```

Your TextView still needs to override the onDetachedFromWindow and other methods as explained in the docs, but you should be able to paste that code as is.